# Best architecture solution for Mixed DML Exceptions inside a Batch

Tags: batch, asynchronous, mixed-dml

I am writing an apex Batch

First I am updating a few EmailTemapltes and then I need to write to a custom object.

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<EmailTemplate> scope) {
    List<EmailTemplate> templates = modifyTemplates(scope);

    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(templates, false);

    insert new Log__c(Name='SomeLog');      
}
```

Now I get `MIXED-DML-OPERATION` exception.

The only solution I found to avoid this exception in my batch, is to put the `insert new Log();` DML into a Queueable class.

Is there a solution to do this DML without creating a new class, Queueable, just for this simple insert?

Comment: One of the approach could be to make batch job stateful and keep the logs in the variables. But that will work only if state is small enough to stay in heap size.

Answer (score 1):

[Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm) can be combined on a single class.

```
public class ServiceClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Queueable {
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    // ...
  }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This allows you to keep all your logic in a single class. Some people might say this violates the Single Responsibility Principle (the S in SOLID), but I'd say that this combination doesn't, as we're talking about the class being responsible for a single thing, namely the implementation of a unit of business logic.

Comment: I thought any object which impacts user access is a setup object, did not know email template is a setup object.
Moreover just wanted to ask are you suggesting to enqueue from each execute method of batch ? If scenario allows wouldn't it be cleaner to chain batch?

Comment: @elijah tbh, I'm not sure why EmailTemplate should trigger mixed DML errors, it's not supposed to. That said, queueable from the execute method would be more efficient than chaining.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please help elaborate more on how the queueable context is executed in this above example . Do you need an explicit call for the Queueable context or does every batchable execute follow queueable execute automatically ?

Comment: @HSG You only get what you specify, so if you use Database.executeBatch, you get the batchable logic, while if you call System.enqueueJob, you'll get the queueable behavior. The Batchable's execute method can call the class as a queueable with `System.enqueueJob(this)` to run in that context with the current state of the batchable.